# Does WCF always use SOAP to send information over your binding?

Tags: xml, wcf, soap, wcf-binding

I understand you can choose from a range of bindings, such as TCP, HTTP, HTTPS etc.

Am I correct in thinking it always uses SOAP to send data over this connection? I am watching a guide to WCF and it is talking about how exceptions are serialized into SOAP and sent to the client. I would have thought that not all bindings would use SOAP to send data, so I am a bit confused about how it works.

Although I understand the fundamentals of WCF, how to set up services and use a proxy on the client, it doesn't seem to have explained exactly how the data is packaged up to send.

Perhaps the answer is obvious, that it just uses XML / SOAP, but I would love to know for sure!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No, not all.  The [WebHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.webhttpbinding.aspx) is designed around REST protocols (HTTP GET, POX, JSON, etc.)

Technically, WCF is just a generic messaging protocol and can use any kind of encoding at all.  The *default* and *most common* encodings are `basicHttpBinding` and `wsHttpBinding`, which are both based around SOAP/XML.

Then you have `netTcpBinding`, which uses a binary message encoding, `netMsmqBinding`, which uses the Microsoft Message Queue (MSMQ) protocol, and so on.  There's really no hard-coded format for messages in WCF.

SOAP has its own specification for serializing exceptions (AKA faults), so the behaviour is always more or less the same when you use a SOAP-based binding; when you use other bindings, the faulting behaviour may be considerably different, in some cases actually swallowing exceptions unless you override the default behaviour (this is what happens in the `webHttpBinding`).

Comment: Does this mean that exceptions are automatically serialized using the appropriate method?

Comment: @SLC: Well, no, it's up to the binding/behavior itself to decide what to do with faults.  `WebHttpBinding`, for example, will actually swallow exceptions unless you set up custom behaviors.

Comment: Thanks, your answer has been incredibly helpful!

Comment: WCF uses netTcpBinding with the message `format` - SOAP/Xml. But the `Encoding` is Binary