# what different message encodings does WCF use and in which scenarios?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wcf, soap, wcf-binding

I am new to WCF, SOAP. I have searched on MSDN and other portals, but did not get a suitable answer. Please pardon me if I am asking something silly, but I really need to get these cleared.

I got some help from these posts. Still would love to know more.

[Does WCF always use SOAP to send information over your binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760839/does-wcf-always-use-soap-to-send-information-over-your-binding?rq=1)

[WCF service, response in SOAP or plain XML, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491430/wcf-service-response-in-soap-or-plain-xml-how?rq=1)

I understand that SOAP is a messaging protocol(which is XML based) and that messages b/w WCF services and clients are encoded primarily in SOAP encoding and then deserialized into dot net objects.

Different bindings support different messaging protocols. Does it mean that SOAP is not used for netTcpBinding, namedPipeBinding and msmqBinding? Rather binary messages are used and XML does not come into picture anywhere. And would this also mean that we would not be able to use XMLSerializers in such cases? I am assuming it would be true as these bindings are not aimed at interoperability.

I read that basicHttpBinding uses simple text encoding. So does it mean that SOAP(or XML) does not come into picture in this case too?

My mind is cluttered with confusion. I would really appreciate your help.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does it mean that SOAP is not used for netTcpBinding, namedPipeBinding and msmqBinding? Rather binary messages

Correct.

> I read that basicHttpBinding uses simple text encoding.

Where did you read that, and what *is* "simple text encoding"?

> So does it mean that SOAP(or XML) does not come into picture in this case too?

No. BasicHttpBinding uses SOAP 1.1, WSHttpBinding uses SOAP 1.2.

> would this also mean that we would not be able to use XMLSerializers in such cases?

Explain "use".

Comment: thanks for your help. I read at msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730879(v=vs.110).aspx, that basicHttpBinding will use text/xml. Pardon me for using the term simple text encoding. My confusion was would it use text/xml only or there could be soap encoding as well? And if yes, is it possible to choose b/w soap and text/xml?